# Build only necessary targets for CPack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a C++ project with multiple targets. I redistribute the project via `.deb` packages which we build with CPack. Some of my `CMakeLists.txt` has `include(CPack)` line. It adds convenient `package` target to the build system, which I can call with `ninja package` to generate the `.deb` packages.

It works fine, but it builds ALL targets in the project, while only few of them actually make their way to the packages. Those targets are unsurprisingly marked with `install(TARGET target_to_be_packaged)` commands. Hence, I only want to build these targets when packaging to save time.

I am aware that I can specify targets manually and then run cpack manually:

```
$ ninja <the targets to be packaged>
$ cpack .
```

However, for this I need to compose the list of targets. While CMake already knows this list of targets! These are the ones mentioned in `install` commands. Is there a way to force CMake to only build necessary targets for me?

Of course, I can substitute the `install` command with some `install_and_add_to_my_package_target` command and then build `my_package` target, but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Related: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/selectively-build-and-pack-targets/657

Comment: CMake doesn't selectively builds targets for `ninja install`: it just makes `install` target to depend from `all`. Packaging and installing are very similar mechanisms, so I guess `package` target depends from `all` too. Note, that aside from `install(TARGET)` command flow, which has clear connection with the targets, there are `install(FILES)` and `install(DIRECTORY)` flows, which may install files not listed in the OUTPUT for a custom command. That is, CMake simply doesn't know which targets are sufficient for install or package the project.

Comment: I don't know if there's a smarter way, but you could at least sooth the pain a little with a build preset. see also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html